# Polyominoes inside a 10x10 grid

Tags: mathematics, polyomino, packing

Can you place five [dominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_(mathematics)), five [trominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino), five [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino), five [pentominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) and five [hexominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexomino) inside a 10x10 grid, such that:

- No two polyominoes overlap
- No two polyominoes of the same size (by area) touch each other orthogonally (horizontally or vertically)

Comment: My previous puzzle was too easy so I made this one.

Comment: Maybe we should have a separate "XXominoes inside XxX grid" site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is also too easy.

This solution is trivial:

> [image]

Comment: I feel so stupid now. It took my program many hours to find a solution.

Comment: What if we disallow straight polyominoes (except dominoes), can it still be solved?

Comment: I did it without straight polyominoes (except dominoes).

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Don't feel bad. It can be hard to come up with good puzzles. Just a tip, though: computers usually aren't the best way to judge the difficulty of a puzzle. Computers don't have imaginations or experience, which are important tools for solving things. Humans, on the other hand, have both those traits.

Answer (score 6):

I can do it with no straight polyominoes (except dominoes):

> [image]

An obvious upper bound for the maximum number of distinct shapes is $1+2+5+5+5=18$, and...

> ...this solution attains that upper bound:
>  [image]

Comment: You could try to maximize the number of distinct polyominoes.

Comment: @DanielMathias Good suggestion.  Done.

Comment: Nice, and with distinct fixed trominoes.

Comment: Very nice! You've solved every version of this problem :)